# making a sharepath file system as svn server

Tags: svn, repository, lan

I see various posts on creating and using a svn repository. But, can someone specify on how to make a directory in LAN as repository and access it from anywhere in the LAN. The file:/// protocol is pointing only to the local system.

Answer (score 1):

Mount shared drive?!

Anyway, **real** SVN-server (http or svnserve) is faster and better for running

Answer (score 1):

You *can* access Subversion repository located on a network share via `file://` protocol using a UNC path. The URL will look like `file://<servername>/<repository>`. When accessing a remote share [you need 2 slashes instead of 3](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1). However I can't recommend this solution and strongly advise to avoid it due to possible technical issues. What is more, this way you don't get any authentication / authorization options, no server-side hook scripts, no access via web browser, etc.

You should install Subversion server that will allow you to access your repositories over HTTP(S). You can set the server to access repositories that are stored on a network drive BTW. For example, as explained here: ["Storing repositories on a network share"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/).